# Azure Active Directory Assigned Users Ignored

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, owin

I have added Azure Authentication to my ASP MVC application by following the guide at https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet. It works as far as restricting access to only users that have accounts in the domain. Non users are rejected.

However, there is a setting in the Azure Management site that allows you to assign a user to an application. This setting does not appear to do anything. All users in the domain can access to site, even if they are not assigned to the application.

I'm looking for a method to select which users are allowed to access the site that can b managed at a Azure domain level.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a bit confusing. The act of assigning a user to an application causes the applications icon (with logo) to appear in the user's access panel (myapps.microsoft.com) from where they can easily sign-in to the application. For some pre-integrated applications like salesforce and box, a profile of the user also gets created in the application.

However for traditional single-tenant and multi-tenant applications, the act of assigning a user yet doesn't block un-assigned users from being able to get a token for the application. This is something we plan to provide in a future release (as a config option) to the application administrator.

To address your current need however, you can query (on behalf of the user) all the users and groups that are assigned to your application in a directory, or you can query (on behalf of the user) all the applications assigned to the user, using the following APIs:

**Query all Users and Groups assigned to an Application:**

`HTTP GET https://graph.windows.net/7fe877e6-a150-4992-bbfe-f517e304dfa0/servicePrincipals/7758ff7a-9c65-4779-af33-f2c2f35aec2
0/appRoleAssignedTo?api-version=1.5`

Where 7fe877e6-a150-4992-bbfe-f517e304dfa0 is the tenantId of the directory (this could be the domain name of the directory too) and 7758ff7a-9c65-4779-af33-f2c2f35aec2 is the objectId of the service principal that represents the application in that directory.

**Query all Applications to which a User is assigned:**

`HTTP GET https://graph.windows.net/7fe877e6-a150-4992-bbfe-f517e304dfa0/users/3a477f6a-6739-4b93-84aa-3be3f8c8e7c2/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.5`

Where 7fe877e6-a150-4992-bbfe-f517e304dfa0 is the tenantId of the directory (this could be the domain name of the directory too) and 3a477f6a-6739-4b93-84aa-3be3f8c8e7c2 is the objectId of the user object.

I am using [AADGraphPowerShell](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2013/12/27/aadgraphpowershell-a-powershell-client-for-windows-azure-ad-graph-api/) to query my directory - and here' the results for the above queries:

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, very useful... Quick question, 

I have tried using HTTP GET https://graph.windows.net/.../users/.../appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.5 with the correct values for my user and app, and also a valid access token, all I get back however is Authorization_RequestDenied error. 
But if i then run Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal -RoleName 'User Account Administrator' -RoleMemberObjectId ... it works. 

I have given the user every permission I can find, and I don't want to give the application full user admin role as it could be a security risk.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You seem to be querying Graph using the OAuth client credential flow (resulting in app only access token). You need to query Graph in the context of a user (all users except guests can enumerate users) - for this use the authorization code grant flow. Search for web app graph API sample in our Guthub repo (AzureAD). Hope that helps